# NSRangeException | Deleting Rows From Table (View)

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

getting the following error upon deleting some rows from my TableView

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 
'-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)'
```

found a similar problem here:
[Crash when moving a row in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775769/crash-when-moving-a-row-in-uitableview)

but the answer:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
    if (!self.tableView.editing) 
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

doesn't seem to work with the newest code -- I'm getting a "Expected a type" error with "NSFetchedResultsController"

any hints?

cheers

edit: seems to have something to do with moved rows from swiped deleting - hope that helps..

edit two: sometimes I get a different error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

the culprit can only be somewhere in the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    favsTwo = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Favorites"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Number of items in my array is: %d", [favsTwo count]);
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Number of items in my array is: %d", indexPath.row+1);
    [favsTwo removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favsTwo forKey:@"Favorites"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [favsTwo removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = _sidebarButton;
    _sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
    _sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

}
```

Comment: Show code for all of your FRC delegate methods.

Comment: I guess it should be in the, just, edited comments...I don't have any FRC code...

Comment: Ok so that answer regarding the NSFetchedResultsController won't be relevant to you as you don't appear to be using that class - that's a class useful for when you wish to populate a tableView with core data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> favsTwo = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Favorites"];

This line gives you an instance of `NSArray`. If you are expecting / wanting a mutable array then you need to use `mutableCopy`:

```
favsTwo = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Favorites"] mutableCopy];
```

---

Also, in `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` you are calling `[favsTwo removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` twice, which is unlikely to be what you want to do. Remove the second call. You should also remove the call to `reloadData` because you are calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:...`.

Comment: half the time I'm getting NSRangeException errors, the other half of the time I'm getting NSInternalInconsistencyException errors because, apparently, the array is immutable

where can I add mutablecopy? in TableView or WillAppear? what's best?

Comment: i added:
`favsTwo = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Favorites"] mutableCopy];`

now I'm just getting 

'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'


errors.... sometimes its (0) and sometimes its (1) (1)